# Is using "placeholder" as an in-field label semantically wrong?

Tags: html, forms

In-field labels are extremely popular now.  They save space and look cool.  There are [many, many ways](https://www.google.com/search?q=in%20field%20labels%20jquery) to accomplish them.  It is now very easy to do using the HTML5 placeholder parameter for form inputs.  You can even then [create backwards compatibility with a bit of jquery](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) if you want to.

But, is it semantically correct to use `placeholder="Name"` instead of `<label>Name</label>` or should a label element always be included and placeholder reserved to guide the user like this:

```
<label for="name">Name</label><input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Jane Doe">
```

If it's generally considered ok to use placeholder as either a label or an example, then that's definitely the easiest way to accomplish this effect.  No javascript needed for modern browsers, no chance of submitting the label as the input value, etc.  What are the semantic and practical drawbacks of doing this, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML5 specification explicitly calls this out. [It says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute):

> The placeholder attribute should not be used as a replacement for a
>   label. For a longer hint or other advisory text, place the text next
>   to the control.
>
> Use of the placeholder attribute as a replacement for a label can
>   reduce the accessibility and usability of the control for a range of
>   users including older users and users with cognitive, mobility, fine
>   motor skill or vision impairments. While the hint given by the
>   control's label is shown at all times, the short hint given in the
>   placeholder attribute is only shown before the user enters a value.
>   Furthermore, placeholder text may be mistaken for a pre-filled value,
>   and as commonly implemented the default color of the placeholder text
>   provides insufficient contrast and the lack of a separate visible
>   label reduces the size of the hit region available for setting focus
>   on the control.

Comment: Well I guess that's pretty unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 spec notwithstanding, It's becoming popular to use the ["Float Label Pattern"](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/float-label-pattern/).  The label starts as a placeholder, but then moves up above the field once text has been entered.

There's a handy tutorial for it here....

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ux-tutorials/implementing-the-float-label-form-pattern/

Comment: That's really cool.  I haven't seen that in use before.  It's great that it not only keeps the semantic label in the original markup, but also addresses the unfortunate effect where you can't remember what field is what as you start to fill the form unless they are really obvious. First name, last name, email is easy to go back and understand, but if it's something like a form with 4 different phone number fields, it's pretty useless after they are filled with standard in-field labels.